# JSONObject searching constraints

Tags: java, json

I receive json, which definitely contains key pointing to json-hash, but when I do

```
JSONArray jsonRecipeTypes = (JSONArray) jRoot.get("dishGroups");
```

jsonRecipeTypes contains null. Are there any search constraints? 
ps: my key is situated on the 2nd lvl of json hierachy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your key is at the second level you won't find it when searching the root. Only attributes of the root object can be queried, i.e. there is no complex search feature here. It's more like a lookup in a map that could contain other maps.

Comment: yeah, just've figured it out. Thanks.